# add button to a array of button in a scrollview

Tags: arrays, swift, button, insert, scrollview

I want to add a another Uibbuton to the array of the ui buttons. When the func is called on the scrollview it is not added. As you can see in the gif below when the add button is pressed nothing is being added. What I would like to do is when the add button is pressed a button title Button 10 is added. Since the button is initialized in view did load I can't think how to do this?

[image]

```
import UIKit
class SwipeableUIScrollView: UIScrollView {

    
    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        
        if view is UIButton || view is UILabel{
            return true
        }
        
        return touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
    }
    
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView:SwipeableUIScrollView!
    var greenView:UIView!

    var addMore:UIButton!
    var counter = 10
    
    var scrollViewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
    
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView = SwipeableUIScrollView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        greenView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        
   
        
        addMore = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        addMore.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addMore.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        addMore.setTitle("add", for: .normal)
        

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.view.addSubview(greenView)
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(addMore)
        
        
        addMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increaseC), for: .touchDown)
        
        scrollViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: scrollView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            addMore.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50.0),
            addMore.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0),
            addMore.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0),
            addMore.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.addMore.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollViewHeightConstraint,
            
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
       
        var leadingAnchor = self.scrollView!.leadingAnchor
       
        for i in 0..<counter{
           
            let t_button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
            t_button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           
            
            t_button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            scrollView.addSubview(t_button)
           
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                t_button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant:5.0),
                t_button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
                t_button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
                t_button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75.0)
            ])
           
            leadingAnchor = t_button.trailingAnchor
            
            t_button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)

           
        }
           
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
              
    }

    

    
    

    
    @objc func increaseC(){
        counter += 1
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Property Observer`。The property observer allows us to perform certain operations when we want a property to change when using properties. That is, some small code blocks that can be run before willSet or didSet after a property value can be changed. To create an attribute observer, add curly braces after the attribute (similar to the practice of calculated attributes)
just like this:

```objectivec
class PropertyObserverExmple {
    var number: Int = 0 {
        willSet(newNumber) {
            print("About to change to \(newNumber)")
        }
        didSet(oldNumber) {
            print("Just changed from \(oldNumber) to \(self.number)")
        }
    }
}

var observer = PropertyObserverExmple()
observer.number = 4
// About to change to 4 ,Just changed from 0 to 4
```

So your example can be modified to this

```objectivec
import UIKit
class SwipeableUIScrollView: UIScrollView {

    
    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        
        if view is UIButton || view is UILabel{
            return true
        }
        
        return touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
    }
    
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView:SwipeableUIScrollView!
    var greenView:UIView!

    var addMore:UIButton!
    var leadingAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor!
    var counter: Int? {
        didSet {
            for i in (oldValue ?? 0)..<(counter ?? 0){
               
                let t_button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
                t_button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               
                
                t_button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                scrollView.addSubview(t_button)
               
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    t_button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant:5.0),
                    t_button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
                    t_button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
                    t_button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75.0)
                ])
               
                leadingAnchor = t_button.trailingAnchor
                
                t_button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)

               
            }
        }
    }
    
    var scrollViewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
    
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView = SwipeableUIScrollView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        greenView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        greenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        
   
        
        addMore = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        addMore.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addMore.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        addMore.setTitle("add", for: .normal)
        

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.view.addSubview(greenView)
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(addMore)
        
        
        addMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increaseC), for: .touchDown)
        
        scrollViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: scrollView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            addMore.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50.0),
            addMore.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0),
            addMore.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0),
            addMore.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.addMore.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollViewHeightConstraint,
            
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
       
        leadingAnchor  = self.scrollView!.leadingAnchor
       
        counter = 10
           
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
              
    }

    

    
    

    
    @objc func increaseC(){
        counter! += 1
    
    }
}
```